# How do I layer an image behind a <div>?

Tags: html, css, image, svg, image-resizing

I've been trying to make a square image that is layered behind a `<div>`. For my website, I'm trying to make it look similar to an album with a CD popping out from the slip, but every attempt I've done to make the image square, layered behind and the same size as the `<div>` seems to not work. It's either on top, or it's overflowing to the bottom of the page.

Here's the HTML I did:

```html
<div class="container">
      <div id="navbar">
        <div id="nav">
          <div>
            <a href="/home.html" target="content"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="/about.html" target="content"><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>About</a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="/portfolio.html" target="content"><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>Work</a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="/extras.html" target="content"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Extras</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
      </div>
      <iframe src="home.html" title="Webpage" id="content" name="content"></iframe>
      
    </div>
</div>
<div class="disk">
      <img src="/images/cd.svg">
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
:root { /* to get the color just type var(--color) */
  --color1:#150F0F; /*DARKEST*/
  --color2:#221918;
  --color3:#2C221F;
  --color4:#423229;
  --color5:#58493D;
  --color6:#8D7357;
  --color7:#BCAA9B;
  --color8:#BCAA9B;
  --color9:#F5DEAD;
  --color10:#FFF9BC; /*BRIGHTEST*/
  
  --border-size:3px;
}

.container {
  min-height: 50vh;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left:10%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(2vw, 260px) auto;
  
  background-color: var(--color9);
  
  border: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: var(--border-size);
  border-bottom-width: var(--border-size);
  border-color: var(--color10);
  
  z-index: 69;
}
#navbar {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  
  padding: 10%;
  
  float: left;
  
  background-color: var(--color7);
  
  font-family: PopMagic;
  font-size: clamp(15px, 4vw, 30px);
  
}
#content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  border:none;
}
.disk {
  min-height: 50vh;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-top: -50vh;
  
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-bottom:100%;
}
.disk img {
  min-height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
}
```

The site I'm using this on can be found [here](https://superkirbylover.neocities.org).

Comment: you want image center and text on top, is it?

Comment: I should probably have provided images on how I wanted it to look... Here's the mockup: https://i.imgur.com/L6BKONX.png
How it currently looks can be seen at: https://superkirbylover.neocities.org

Comment: ok I see. You are already using grid in the container you can solve your design this way. Put at least 5 columns in your container grid, and 3 rows. Rows: space tope, content middle, space bottom. Cols: space, nav, text content, image cd, space. Playing with that it's easy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It will be hard to help you without knowing what do you want to achieve and your current progress. Please upload the current version of your code to your website (right now there is no disk element there) and share the link in the description. The image of what you want to achieve also would be helpful.

Comment: Of course!! My apologies. I updated the code on the website.

Answer (score 0):

As you may expect there are as many approaches as developers.

You should consider how your layout is constructed at the moment because there is simply not enough space for your disc element.

If I were you I would get rid the following `div`

```
<div class="disk">
  <img src="/images/cd.svg">
</div>
```

and try to use `::after` psuedo-element instead.

```
...
.container {
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 160px 0 0;
  background-color: #0000;

  ::after {
    right: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/images/cd.svg);
  }
}
...
```

Please don't expect the final solution here but take above code as a bunch of clues which may help to solve your problem.

Comment: This does seem to point me in the right direction!! I'll experiment around and see if I can get something I'm happy with.